# ADF Azure Data-Factory loop over folder syntax - wilcard?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i'm tryimg to loop over a diffrent **countries** folder that got fixed sub folder named **survey** (i.e Spain/survey , USA/survey ).

where and how I Need to define a wildcard / parameter for the countries so I could loop over all the files that in the survey folder ?

what is the right wildcard syntax ? ( the equivalent of - like 'survey%' in SQL) ?

I tried several ways to define it with no success and I would be happy to get some help on this - Thanks !

Comment: Hey Ben, Is there any fixed number of country values or are those dynamic?

Comment: its a fixed list . .I just tried to create a names table and pass it as a paremeter to the file fath wild card . it worked but now I have other problem... I think I wrote the filename wild card wrong ( survey?) to get all files that starts with survey .what is the right syntax ? ( the equivalent of - like 'survey%' in SQL) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if the list of paths are static, you can create a parameter or add it in a SQL database and get that result from a lookup activity.
Pass the output to a for each activity and within foreach activity use a copy activity.
You can parameterize the input dataset to get the file paths thereby you need not think of any wildcard characters but use the actual paths itself.
Hope this is helpful.